# Car turns off if ignition is turned while driving

Tags: ignition, ignition-key, lincoln

I have 2009 Lincoln Town Car (230000 miles). I have a very interesting problem. The car drives flawlessly. However, the dashboard lights turn on and off intermittently. (This seems to be can common problem with the Town Car).

There's a weird problem I have. If I turn the ignition when the car is already on, the engine turns off. (While on other cars you just hear a clicking noise of the starter). Normally this is not a problem, but I absentmindedly turned it while driving and the whole car shut down and I had to navigate to the side of the road and put the car into park and restart the engine.

I am wondering if anyone knows what can be causing the issue? Interestingly, when the car is on park, the engine turns back on when the key is returned to its normal position, but when I'm driving the only way to turn the engine back on is to shift t to park.

Comment: Why would you turn the ignition while driving?

Comment: Just drive the car the way it is meant to be driven. Drive with both hands on the wheel instead of fiddling with the controls. Don't touch the ignition key again until you have parked up and engaged the brake.

Comment: Aside: I have a Skoda where the dashboard light turns off and on unexpectedly. It took me ages to discover this stupid "feature" was supposed to remind me to turn on the headlights when the car's engineers think they are supposed to be on (like in broad daylight).